# bumblebee-status returns error in i3wm while i3status and i3blocks both work fine

Tags: window-manager, i3, xubuntu, python3

I am running the i3 window manager on Xubuntu Yakketty, kernel 4.9.9

When I try to use the bumblebee-status project [1](https://github.com/tobi-wan-kenobi/bumblebee-status) as my status bar, I get an error message "Error: status_command process exited unexpectedly (exit 1)". However, both i3status and i3blocks work just fine.

Any idea what prevents bumblebee-status from running successfully ?

Comment: Please, do not post the same question on different StackExchange sites at the same time. Have a look at [this question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your status_command may be wrong.  Verify your bar { } section is written out correctly and/or share the full section here.

It's also possible you don't have the proper python modules installed.  Try running the command in a terminal and see what happens.  For example, the command:

```
~/.i3/bumblebee-status/bumblebee-status -m nic disk:home load cpu memory 
battery date time pasink pasource dnf -p time.format="%H:%M CW %V" 
date.format="%a, %b %d %Y" home.path=/home -t solarized-powerline
```

May yield the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/adahl/.i3/bumblebee-status/bumblebee-status", line 36, in <module>
    main()
File "/home/adahl/.i3/bumblebee-status/bumblebee-status", line 18, in main
    inp=inp,
File "/home/adahl/.i3/bumblebee-status/bumblebee/engine.py", line 79, in __init__
    self._aliases = self._read_aliases()
File "/home/adahl/.i3/bumblebee-status/bumblebee/engine.py", line 116, in _read_aliases
    mod = importlib.import_module("bumblebee.modules.{}".format(module["name"]))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
File "/home/adahl/.i3/bumblebee-status/bumblebee/modules/nic.py", line 9, in <module>
    import netifaces
ImportError: No module named netifaces
```

So, `dnf install python-netifaces` (on Fedora) fixes the issue.  In your case, something like `apt-get install python-netifaces` may work -- or using `pip` if you're more comfortable with that.

Comment: Glad to hear it!